# bitcoin cash bitcoin-cli cannot connect to RPC server

Tags: bitcoin

I'm running a bitcoin server and I validate its working by running bitcoin-cli getinfo. I have a new bitcoin-cash server which basically sets up the same but when I run a cli command it errors. 
When I run this command from the server;

```
bitcoin-cli -rpcuser bitcoin -stdinrpcpass REDACTED_1aAbY -conf /data01/bitcoin/bitcoin.conf -rpcport 8332 getinfo
```

I get this result;
`error: Could not locate RPC credentials. No authentication cookie could be found, and RPC password is not set.  See -rpcpassword and -stdinrpcpass.  Configuration file: (/home/ubuntu/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf)`

No matter the flags I use on bitcoin-cli I get the same error. The error indicates a conf files should be at /home/ubuntu/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf but that file and dir don't exist.

My server config looks like;

```
server=1
txindex=1
zmqpubrawtx=tcp://127.0.0.1:28332
zmqpubhashblock=tcp://127.0.0.1:28332
rpcallowip=127.0.0.1
rpcallowip=0.0.0.0/0
rpcuser=bitcoin
rpcpassword=REDACTED_1aAbY
rpcbind=0.0.0.0
rest=1
daemon=1
datadir=/data01/bitcoin
rpcworkqueue=128
whitelist=0.0.0.0/0
rpcallowip=::/0
printtoconsole=1
```

If I stop the bitcoind exe from running then I get this error;

````
Make sure the bitcoind server is running and that you are connecting to the correct RPC port.```
That tells me at least I'm running against what I think I am.
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The (local) cli command is independent of rpc authentication.
Just try the command like this:

> bitcoin-cli getinfo
>
> bitcoin-cli -rpcport=8332 getinfo

Answer (score 4):

As it turns out, you can't connect to the rpc server while the server is still downloading blocks. Once it finishes, you can connect to the server. Using bitcoin-cli getinfo was the original problem.